# android sound is starting multiple times when the condition is true

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app that play a sound whenever the speed of the phone is over specific number, and it worked with me but I am having a little problem which is sound is duplicated and play multiple times which sounds like echo , but I need only one sound to keep playing and stop once the value speed is below the limit.

here is my code:

```
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged (Location location){

   float nCurrentSpeed;

    TextView txt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);


    boolean needToPlay = nCurrentSpeed > 20.0;

    // if need to play, play when it's already not playing
    if (needToPlay && !mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();
    }


    boolean needToPause = nCurrentSpeed <= 20.0;

    // if need to pause then pause only if it's playing
    if (needToPause && mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
    }


}
```

Comment: `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);` - You are creating a new object everytime `onLocationChanges` , for this new object sound has never been played that's why it's playing again and again. Move this line outside the method, this way your media player will be initialized only once

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MediaPlayer mp ;


@Override
 public void onLocationChanged (Location location){

   float nCurrentSpeed;
   if(mp==null){
     mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
     }
    

    boolean needToPlay = nCurrentSpeed > 20.0;

    // if need to play, play when it's already not playing
    if (needToPlay && !mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();
    }


    boolean needToPause = nCurrentSpeed <= 20.0;

    // if need to pause then pause only if it's playing
    if (needToPause && mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
    }


}
```